# Illustrator Gradient Changes on Export!

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, gradient

I have an image that's an application icon for a webapp. It's a pretty simple layout. The background is a rounded rectangle with a light grey to grey gradient.

When I export this image as an .svg, everything looks right EXCEPT the gradient looks like it's rotated 180°. It also looks a little darker. Any ideas what's going on here?

In the image attached to this post, the one on the right is the real original one from the illustrator file. And the one on the right is what I get when I export is as an svg.

[image]

Comment: Hi. How are you viewing the SVG?  Have you tried viewing it in your browser?

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes that screenshot image is the svg being viewer in the browser.

Comment: I can't really work out what's causing the problem. Sorry. It could potentially be a bug, but I'm not sure this can really be answered without access to the files. One thing to check is that you are not using any effects, as these don't always translate so well into SVG.  Gradients can pose some problems, so too can layers with blending modes.  Try to keep your design a simple as possible.

Comment: This is truly as simple as it looks. Some very simple objects atop a rounded rectangle which has a grey to grey color gradient for a fill color. Very simple. And yet somehow it fails every single time.

Comment: OK, I'll give this one more try. Instead of using 1 grey colour in a gradient, make the gradient between two solid colours of grey (with no transparency).  The problem might be the way the browser is rendering the gradient if there is transparency in it. Also try it in different browsers - such as Chrome, Firefox, Edge, or Safari. If this doesn't work, I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: The exported SVG has the same incorrect background gradient in Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Photoshop, and when opened back up in Illustrator.
The gradient is already two solid grey colors. There are no transparencies anywhere. This whole thing makes no sense.

Comment: I did some more poking around with both the original .ai doc and the .svg doc opened in illustrator at the same time. It seems like the exact same gradient settings give completely different results on the SVG doc. What I'm seeing makes no sense, it's literally just randomly reversing the colors.

Comment: Ok so instead of matching the color values between the two docs, I adjusted the greys on the high and low side of the background gradient so they visually matched the illustrator doc very closely. Then I saved it. When I reopened it, it was SUPER dark. It seems like this version of Illustrator has some major SVG problems. Which is a huge bummer since i try to do all my web graphics in SVG these days.

Comment: Hmmm . . . is the Illustrator document in RGB?

Comment: So my hack workaround fix was to save a copy of the doc as an eps, then copy that file over to an old MacOS Snow Leopard virtual machine running Illustrator CS5! Then from there, save for web, as an SVG. And it saved just fine, and the gradient is just the way it should be. That's about the quality level I expected for an adobe product that isn't photoshop.

Comment: You know you don't really have to resort to using old versions of software.  Inkscape which is free and open source, for example, is a very good SVG editor.  Illustrator isn't the only game in town.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure these are the same file? The crosshairs are missing from the left image and the word pain is missing from the right. Some of the outline of North America is different too. Makes me think that these are different files, different versions of the same file, or that you're only exported some layers.

Comment: Well it is not "the same file" at all. The right file is the original illustrator document. Then I exported as SVG and the left image is that svg document. That is why the guides are not there. I don't see any differences in north America. And the word "pain" is the worth "path" because the cursor happened to be on the path when I took the screen shot.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. The gradient colour at the bottom of each image appears to be the same, they just start with different colours at the top. Is the gradient a straightforward colour gradient, or a created by layering a partially transparent gradient on top of a block of colour?. I would think that the former would convert to SVG better. Ditto Billy Kerr's comments about effects / blending modes.

Comment: Just a regular old gradient. From one tone of gray to another.